# Closing SWT application when focus goes to another application

Tags: swt

I want that when the focus of the application moves to another application the application will be closed, for example, if the user clicks somewhere on the desktop the application should be closed.

I tried to use focus listener but it does not work. What's the solution to this?

Comment: I guess you also need to add an `SWT.Deactivate` listener to the shell and exit the application if this event occurs.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the focus listener, you need to add an `SWT.Deactivate` listener to the shell and exit the application if this event occurs.

For example:

```java
Shell shell = ...
shell.addListener( SWT.Deactivate, event -> shell.close() );
...
while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
  if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
    display.sleep();
}
```

The example assumes that `shell` is the only shell, thus causing the program to end.